# How to validate json with json schema in NJsonSchema c#

Tags: c#, jsonschema, njsonschema

As part of contract tests I have to validate json response I got from rest-endpoint against json-schema present in a file. I'm using NJsonSchema and was not able to perform this.

Json-schema in file is as something below

```
{
        'type': 'object',
        'properties': {
            'remaining': {
                'type': 'integer',
                'required': true
            },
            'shuffled': {
                'type': 'boolean',
                'required': true
            }
            'success': {
                'type': 'boolean',
                'required': true
            },
            'deck_id': {
                'type': 'string',
                'required': true
            }
        }
    }
```

Json I have to validate is something like below

```
{ 'remaining': 52, 'shuffled': true, 'success': true, 'deck_id': 'b5wr0nr5rvk4'}
```

Can anyone please throw some light (with examples) on how to validate json with jsonschema using NJsonSchema or Manatee.Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disclaimer: I'm the author of Manatee.Json.

That looks like a *draft-03* schema (the `required` keyword was moved out of the property declaration in *draft-04*).  I'm not sure if NJsonSchema supports schemas that old; Manatee.Json doesn't.

JSON Schema is currently at *draft-07*, and *draft-08* is due out soon.

My suggestion is to rewrite the schema as a later draft by moving the `required` keyword into the root as a sibling of `properties`.  The value of `required` becomes an array of strings containing the list of properties that are required.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "remaining": { "type": "integer" },
    "shuffled": { "type": "boolean" },
    "success": { "type": "boolean" },
    "deck_id": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "required": [ "remaining", "shuffled", "success", "deck_id" ]
}
```

By doing this, it'll definitely work with Manatee.Json, and I *expect* it'll work with NJsonSchema as well.

If you have specific questions about using Manatee.Json, hit me up on my Slack workspace.  There's a link on the GH readme.

Comment: Thank you @gregsdennis.