# jsonschema not throwing error on missing required property

Tags: javascript, jsonschema

I have the following schema:

```
const LIST_EVENTS = {
    "id": "/listEvents",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "filter": {
            "$ref": "/MarketFilter",
            "required": true
        },
        "locale": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

From debugging, I can see that the object being sent to the validation is:

```
{
    marketFilter: {
        eventTypeIds: [ '1' ],
        marketStartTime: {
            from: '2018-12-15T00:00:00+00:00',
            to: '2018-12-15T23:59:59+00:00'
        }
    }
}
```

`marketFilter` does not match the name of `filter` in the schema. To my understanding, seeing as this is a required property, this should have been flagged in the `errors` array of the validation result but it is not. This is my validation result:

```
ValidatorResult {
  instance:
    { marketFilter: { eventTypeIds: [Array], marketStartTime: [Object] } },
  schema:
    { id: '/listEvents',
      type: 'object',
      properties: { filter: [Object], locale: [Object] } },
  propertyPath: 'instance',
  errors: [],
  throwError: undefined,
  disableFormat: false }
```

I thought that it was possible that it did not mind about the naming convention so I removed the property altogether and still, an error is not logged with this being the validation result:

```
ValidatorResult {
  instance: {},
  schema:
    { id: '/listEvents',
      type: 'object',
      properties: { filter: [Object], locale: [Object] } },
  propertyPath: 'instance',
  errors: [],
  throwError: undefined,
  disableFormat: false }
```

I have many schemas and they are all added via `.addSchema` method

Comment: What JSON Schema implementation are you using? You have a JavaScript tag, but there are many libraries.

Comment: Additionally, you should try moving the `required` out, like I describe in [this answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53454670/878701). Using the most recent schema draft is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues with your schema. The main issue is that your `required` keyword is ignored because it is next to `$ref`. When an object with a `$ref` keyword is encountered where a schema is expected, it's treated as a JSON Reference only. It's not treated as a schema. A JSON Reference only has semantics for the `$ref` keyword. Everything else is ignored. You could fix your problem by isolating the `$ref` in you schema.

```
"filter": {
    "allOf": [{ "$ref": "/MarketFilter" }],
    "required": true
}
```

The other problem is the use of the boolean form of the `required` keyword. This usage of the `required` keyword was removed from the JSON Schema specification years ago. Unless you are specifically writing JSON Schemas against the draft-03 specification (unlikely, it's long out of date), you should be using the array form of `required`. Some older implementations allow you to use both forms, but that's not a good idea. You should be targeting a single specification and not mix keywords from two different versions of specification.

```
{
    "id": "/listEvents",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "filter": {
            "$ref": "/MarketFilter"
        },
        "locale": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": ["filter"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have found a work-around that is also described in the docs. I have added the `required` array property to the schema and added `filter` to it. This now threw an error.

However, the documentation states that the `required` property on the property itself should work the same. Is this potentially an issue with the package or is there different behaviours if the property is a reference?

Comment: can you please delete this answer and post it below your question? This answer is more likely a comment :)